# Update/Save data in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, save

I hope someone can help me solve this problem
I am using spring and JPA to save data. 
When I try to save calling my DAO, not all the data gets saved.

Consider the following structure

```
class User
var name
var surname

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
set<Address> address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
set<Job>job;


class Address
List<AddressList>addressList;

class Job
List<JobList>jobList;
```

What basically happens is that name and surname changes but if I make any change related to the address or job class, these aren't committed.
However, if I delete the user, it works,if I retrieve the user information(addresses,jobs),these are retrieved correctly.

Any advice on what could be the issue?

Comment: it seems like your address or job table have read only may be? are you getting any error or exception defenetely I think?

Comment: I have made some changes and now I am getting the following error:
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging
This happens if the sets cascadeType is set to Persist; If I set them to Merge or ALL then there's no error but all the child elements get deleted like I explained in my previous comment to the advice on using cascadeType.MERGE

Answer (score 0):

You're only cascading the persist operation. When you update an already persisted entity, a merge operation will be performed. So, I suggest to cascade merge operation as well: `CascadeType.MERGE` if you want to save the related entities on update, too.

Comment: I changed all the 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
to
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
but now what happens is that the data not only is not storing but it's getting deleted
I had a user with 1 address and 2 jobs
I added an additional address and the two jobs disappeared, the additional address wasn't added but the one that was there is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try cascade type all --- CascadeType.ALL.

For orphan removals you should use :

CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN - if you are using hibernate

orphanRemoval = true - if you are using jpa 2.0

manual removal - if none of the above apply

Answer (score 0):

Have decalre your transient object `@Transient` ? ok BTw --

follw below steps:

1. declare your teansient objects as `@Transient`
2. Use  cascade type all --- `CascadeType.ALL`.
3. try to flush your entitymanager by using `entityManager.flush()` then perform `persist()` or `merge()` operation.